# How to connect unconnected git histories?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, git-merge

we have a quite strange git history in our project. First, there was another project which might have the following history:

repo1:

```
a---b---c
```

then there was our project which had

repo2:

```
u---v---w
```

as we needed repo1 in the code of repo2, a "smart" programmer used read-tree to read the last commit (c) of repo1 into w, so now we had

```
u---v---w---w'
```

where w' had the commit c in it without having its history. Then there were some changes to both repositorires resulting in the following histories:

```
a---b---c---d---e

u---v---w---w'---x---y
```

now we want to clean up the mess and incorporate the changes of repo1 into our repository. However, when simply merging the two repositories, we gain an extreme number of conflicts, as the branches do not share history (actually they do, but git doesn't know), so git cannot perform a three way merge.

So how can we do the three way merge? Is there a way to "add" the missing history edge, i.e. create something like this:

```
a---b---c---d---e
          \
u---v---w--w'---x---y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter `repo2` and add `repo1` as a remote

```
git add remote repo1 url_of_repo1
```

Fetch `repo1`'s history

```
git fetch repo1
```

Now your `repo2` history should be

```
a---b---c---d---e  repo1/master

u---v---w--w'  master
```

As you can see, `repo1`'s and `repo2` histories are still unrelated and have no commits in common.

Now you are free to `merge` or `rebase` the two lines

With `merge` you will do

```
git checkout master
git merge repo1/master

a---b---c---d---e  repo1/master
                  \
u---v---w--w'------x  master
```

With `rebase` you will end up with a linear history

```
git checkout -b rebasing repo1/master
git rebase master
git branch -f master
git checkout master
git branch -D rebasing


u---v---w--w'-a---b---c---d---e  master
```

You will have to solve conflicts, of course. But it will be just a one-shot issue.

To make your life easier, before rebasing or merging, you could also get rid of the `w'` commit with a

```
git checkout master
git reset master^1
```

which will move your `master` branch on the `w` commit

Comment: Additionally, for git ~1.7.3?, if you know `repo1/master` is "correct" you could auto resolve using `git rebase -Xtheirs master` (or conversely, `-Xours`)